Show that for all $\phi \in V , \int_a^b u(x)\phi (x)=0$
Let $V=\{ \phi \in C^{\infty}_c(]a,b[) : \int_a^b \phi (x)=0\}$
and  $u\in L^1(]a,b[)$  such that for all $\phi \in C^{\infty}_c(]a,b[)$ we have $$\int_a^b u(x)\phi' (x)=0$$
Show that for all $\phi \in V$ $$\int_a^b u(x)\phi (x)=0$$

You can rewrite the fact that $\int_a^b u(x) \phi'(x) dx = 0$ for all compactly supported $\phi$ as $\int_a^b u(x) v(x) dx = 0$ for all $v \in C_c^\infty((a, b))$ such that $v = \phi'$ for $\phi \in C_c^\infty((a, b))$. Your goal is to then show that the set of $v$ I just described is precisely $V$.
